# How to instanciate same dialog in MFC C++?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, dialog, tabcontrol

I want to build a MFC dialog in which I add a simple `TabControl`. I want my tab pages to be instances of the same `CDialog`, but with some different parameters (such as which buttons are shown, for example).

I am using Visual Studio 2008.

I am relatively new to C++, but I've seen that each component (CButton, CDialog) has its own ID (which is static, so I theoretically I can't instance the same component twice).

I would like to know how to do something like this:

```
for (index = 0 to tabNumber) {
  name = "TAB"+index;
  tabCtrl.add(new CustomDialog(name, i));
}
```

Comment: There's actually no problem creating the same dialog as many times as you want. The control IDs are always in reference to the parent dialog window, so there's no conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give different TabID while creating item.

```
OnInitDialog()
```

{
m_cTab.Init();

```
m_cTab.InsertItem(0,"Register new user");//tabID=0
m_cTab.InsertItem(1,"Identify");// TabID=1
```

//Register new user
    m_cTab.CreateButton("Load Image",23,TabID=0, 0, m_cTab.RightOf(22)+15, m_cTab.TopOf(19),60);
//Identify
m_cTab.CreateButton("Register User",24,TabID=1,P_LEFT,0, m_cTab.TopOf(20) ,60);

```
}
```